# Fourier series of: $[\log(\sin x)]^2$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What is the Fourier expansion of:

> $${ \left[ \log\left( \sin x \right)  \right]  }^{ 2 }$$

This is a well known Fourier series:

> $$-\log(\sin x )=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}+\log(2)$$

I couldn't proceed through this. I also tried using: $\sin x=\frac { { e }^{ ix }-{ e }^{ -ix } }{ 2i } $

But still I couldn't get it. Please help.

Is it possible to get a general form of Fourier expansion for:

> $${ \left[ \log\left( \sin x \right)  \right]  }^{ n }$$

Comment: Do you have to use the given fourier series or just calculate it? And over which interval do you want to calculate the fourier series?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat from 0 to pi/2. I wanted to use it for various intervals just like the latter one.

Comment: look at $\log(1 + ae^{ix})$ for $a \in ]0; 1[$ and let $a\to 1$

Comment: @user1952009 I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: hint : power series. and the multiplication of two power series is the power series whose coefficients are the convolution of the two sequences of coefs

Comment: @user1952009 ooh I tried that also. But it became to messy. There wasn't a good closed form for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it satisfies you, but using $\log \sin x$ expansion I found the follwing: $$
(\ln\sin x)^2=\ln^2 2-\left (x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )^2 + \left (x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )\sin x-2\ln2\cos x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}2\left (\frac{(k-2)!}{k!}-\frac{\ln2}{k}\right )\cos2kx+\left (x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )\frac{\sin2kx}{k}
$$
If you like it I will give you details to find it (and, with a strong effort, also the formulation for any power).

Comment: Even I tried that but it became too messy to group. Nice one!